# Error Importing "mongodb" with typescript

Tags: typescript, node-mongodb-native

When compiling any typescript program that just imports `mongodb`, i get 12 errors like:

```
node_modules/mongodb/mongodb.d.ts:3309:5 - error TS2416: Property 'end' in type 'GridFSBucketWriteStream' is not assignable to the same property in base type 'WritableStream'
```

To reproduce is simple with node TLS (v16.13.1), & a empty directory, just run:

```
npm i mongodb typescript
echo "import mongodb  from 'mongodb'" > index.ts
npx tsc index
```

Comment: I think your example has a mistake. It should be `import * as mongodb from 'mongodb'` since mongodb does not have a default export.

Comment: I'm encountering the same issue, though using Mongoose, which depends on MongoDB's native Node driver. The solution I came to was downgrading Mongoose to the last major release, which I assume downgraded the MongoDB driver. Not sure if that fits your usecase.

Comment: I too just encountered this same error today.  mongodb 4.2.2  Not using mongoose.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Sam, I changed the example to your suggestion, but got the same result

Comment: Thanks Quontas,  I can also get it to work with the v3.x.x of the mongdb driver, but none of the 4.x.x versions work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like `mongodb` npm released 4.3.0 last night (2022-01-06) that now resolves this issue!  [changelog](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/HEAD/HISTORY.md) includes the issue here: [#3088](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/pull/3088)

v4 now compiles without these errors!

Answer (score 7):

i referred this https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/pull/3088

```
npm i @types/node@16.11.7 --save-dev
```

Comment: That one worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

I have to downgrade my @types/node to version 17.0.0

"@types/node": "17.0.0", worked for me

read more: https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/pull/3088

Answer (score 1):

mongodb 4.3.0 fix this issue for me.
I use mongoose but I put `"mongodb": "^4.3.0"` in my dependencies to force the update. I don't know if this is the right thing to do but it works while waiting for mongoose to update.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unable to reproduce your problem in my local environment, so I think it is a problem probably related to some other package in your project.

As suggested on [this issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/27873#issuecomment-491517698), you should try deleting your `package-lock.json` and generating it again with npm.

Comment: I tried this as suggested, and additionally, removed my "node-modules" folder.  This did not solve the problem for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've just tried it on a 2nd machine, Ubuntu 21.04 again, with the same result.  There is no package-lock.json before I run the "npm i mongodb typescript" it just gets the latest versions.  I also tried to delete the $HOME/.npm folder with no luck.  I dont understand it